# Understanding the steps taken in a calculation of the maximum profile likelihood of a simple ODE, given some data

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations, estimation, log-likelihood

I'm trying to understand a calculation made in a paper (section 2 from the supplementary contents of `Likelihood based observability analysis and confidence intervals for predictions of dynamic models. Kreutz C, Raue A and Timmer J. BMC Systems Biology 6, 120, 2012`) for analytically determining a maximum likelihood estimate for a simple differential equation:

$[1]$
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=-θ$$

where $x(0)=1$, we have a single data point $y=0.9$ for $x$ at time point $t=1$ (with assumed Gaussian measurement noise $N(0,0.1^2)$.

The solution to this equation is:

$[2]$

$$ x(t)=-exp(-θt)      $$

The log-likelihood is:

$[3]$

$$ LL(y|θ)=log[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2*pi*sigma^2}}exp(\frac{-0.9 - exp(-θ))^2}{2*sigma^2})] $$

$[4]$

$$=-50(0.9-exp(-θ))^2+c $$

Where $ c = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2*pi*sigma^2}}$

$Question 1$: What steps were taken to get from equation $[3]$ to equation $[4]$?

The maximum likelihood estimate is obtained by:

$[5]$

$$\frac{\partial{LL(y|θ)}}{\partial{θ}}=0 $$

therefore (they used the `if and only if` symbol in the paper`)

$[6]$

$$ -50θ(0.9 -exp(-θ))=0$$

and the estimated $θ$ is (they used the `implies` arrow in the paper) :

$[7]$

$$-log(0.9)=0.1054 $$

$Question 2$: What steps were taken to get from $[5]$ to $[6]$? Where did the constant $c$ go? why is there $[5]$ no longer squared in $[6]$ and why is 50 multiplied by $θ$ in $[6]$?

$Question 3$: What steps were taken to get from $[6]$ to $[7]$?

I apologize if these questions seem a bit basic or obvious but I don't have a mathematical background and I have to try and understand this. Given that, it'd be great if you'd kindly be explicit in your answers. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q1:** Use the property of the log function $\log (a\cdot b) = \log(a) + \log(b)$. You obtain
\begin{equation}
 LL(y\vert \theta) = \log(c) + \log(\exp(\frac{(0.9-\exp(-\theta))^2}{2 \sigma})).
\end{equation}
Then, use the fact that the log function is the inverse of the exponential: $\log(\exp(a)) = a$.

**Q2:** In [4], the function $LL(y \vert \theta)$ is given. According to [5], the derivative of that expression to $\theta$ should be zero. Use the property of the derivative that the derivative of a sum is the sum of their derivatives: $\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\left[f(y \vert\theta) + g(y\vert\theta)\right] = \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}f(y \vert\theta) + \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}g(y \vert\theta)$. Then, you can use the property that the derivative of a constant is zero. In other words, $c$ does not depend on $\theta$, so the derivative of $c$ to $\theta$ is zero.
To calculate the derivative to $\theta$ of 
\begin{equation}
f(y\vert \theta) =  -50(0.9 - \exp(-\theta))^2,
\end{equation}
use the fact that you can write $f(y \vert \theta)$ as 
\begin{equation}
 f(y\vert \theta) = F ( G (y\vert \theta)),
\end{equation}
with $F(x) = - 50 x^2$ and $G(y \vert \theta) = -0.9 - \exp(-\theta)$. Then, the chain rule for derivatives gives you the required answer. Note that there is a typo in [6]: it should say
\begin{equation}
 -100\,\exp(-\theta)(0.9 - \exp (-\theta)) = 0. \tag{*}
\end{equation}

**Q3:** Equation $(*)$ can be solved for $\theta$. Note that it has the form $a \cdot b = 0$, which means that $a=0$ or $b=0$. Now, $\exp(-\theta)$ can never be zero because an exponential can never be zero, so this means that
\begin{equation}
 0.9 - \exp(-\theta) = 0. \quad \Rightarrow \quad \exp(-\theta) = 0.9.
\end{equation}
Using the log function on both sides of the equation gives the required result.

Comment: Thank you very much - Very helpful!